# ASP.NET MVC 5 vertical table header

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Could anyone please suggest me to switch Headers from top to left column vertically. I would also appreciate to know, if there are any jquery plugin to edit such tables directly from grid with examples :) As I am a newbie...

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Age)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Country)
        </th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Age)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Country)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhWyL.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This...

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </td>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
        }
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Age)
        </td>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Age)
            </td>
        }
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Country)
        </td>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Country)
            </td>
        }
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id })
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id })
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            </td>
        }
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hello, Amit Thanks for your answer. Could you also suggest me any jquery plugins for such operations. As I have a huge amount of Data, I think it is better to edit tables in same view.

Answer (score 0):

You can show the data in a table horizontally, but for that you should have to select the data in a list format. In order to do so, you have to change the structure of your `ViewModel` to:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public List<string> Name {get; set;}
    public List<int> Age {get; set;}
    public List<string> Country {get; set;}
}
```

and into View you have to use table as::

```
@model ProjectName.Models.ViewModels.TestViewModel

<table class="table table-striped table-hover">

    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Name)
        {
         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        }
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Age)
        </th>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Age)
        {
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Age)
        }
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Country)
        </th>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Country)
        {
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Country)
        }
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Could you also suggest me any jquery plugins for such operations. As I have a huge amount of Data, I think it is better to edit tables in same view.